# AutoCloseable contract: writing to resource allowed in close()?

Tags: java

I've stumbled across the following construct in-house:

```
class OurXmlWriter implements AutoCloseable {
    private XMLStreamWriter streamWriter;
    public OurXmlWriter(OutputStream stream) {
        streamWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance()
                        .createXMLStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            // is this allowed?
            streamWriter.writeEndDocument();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            try {
                streamWriter.close();
            } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            streamWriter = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem we've had with this is:

```
try (OurXmlWriter writer = new OurXmlWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"))) {
    writer.writeStartTag();
    // write some data elements correctly
    throw new OutOfMemoryError(); // that's not done explicitly but happens
}
```

This still calls `close()` - which is fine as such but results in the xml being closed correctly (albeit unreliably because I'm sure it's not guaranteed to succeed after an `Error`).

So the issue is basically that the XML is valid although we'd prefer it not be (so the output is not accidentally processed further in case the Error is missed). I'm pondering on how to best approach the situation - remove the end tag writing from `close()` - which would require a lot of analysis retesting - or just not use try-with-resource to have control over whether it is called.

But the general question I have is:
Does the `AutoCloseable` contract allow to still write into your resources when you're told to `close()`? I've been reading the javadoc but it doesn't really explicitly disallow it. Am I missing something?

Comment: I suspect at the end of the day this is a matter of opinion. [The JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) does not *disallow* writing in `close`. So does that mean it's allowed in terms of the contract of the interface? (My answer: Yes. But I can totally see the argument for "no" as well, hence...opinion-based.) (The obvious follow-on question "...and is it a good idea?" would be even more opinion-based.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I also suspected it's a matter of opinion - was somewhat reluctant to post the question, but am hoping someone show up with an authoritative source saying it's properly defined either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples in the Java Standard class libraries where the `close()` method **has to** perform a write.  One such example is `DeflaterOutputStream` whose javadoc states:

> Writes remaining compressed data to the output stream and closes the underlying stream.

The point being that the last bit of a compressed stream can only be when you know that the stream is being closed.  Flushing is not sufficient.

So combine this with @Kayaman and there is clear evidence that it is permitted for a stream to perform a write during `close()`.

(And another example would be `BufferedOutputStream` where `close()` does the equivalent of a `flush()` call if required.)

Comment: Yeah I'd consider the standard library implentation "authoritative" ;) It _is_ somewhat intuitive to be writing remaining data on closing, but pretty awkward when doing so due to handling of an `Error`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically there's nothing in the Javadoc to indicate it wouldn't be allowed, and in fact it says that

> Note that unlike the `close` method of `java.io.Closeable` this
>   `close` method is **not** required to be idempotent.  In other words,
>   calling this `close` method more than once may have some visible side
>   effect, unlike `Closeable.close` which is required to have no effect
>   if called more than once.

which allows for side effects and doesn't even require the method to be idempotent. Considering that writing the end of the document is a relatively unsurprising side effect, I'd say that's alright. But of course just because it's not forbidden doesn't mean it's allowed, YMMV, opinion based, consult your in-house rulebook etc.